# The caculated number field return 0 after submit form on Gravity form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I cut a 11 characters number field to 4 character by JavaScript in Gravity form. In final I use the output number, in another number field. On form page everything is OK and the number field cut correctly but on back-end  side I receive 0.

This is what I use to cut number field:

`<script>
gform.addFilter( 'gform_calculation_format_result', function(formattedResult, result, formulaField, formId, calcObj,trimmedresult, output){

    if ( formulaField.field_id == '73' ){
    formattedResult = gformFormatNumber(result, !gformIsNumber(formulaField.rounding) ? -1 : formulaField.rounding, ',', '');
    output = formattedResult.substr(6, 4);
    }
    return output;
});
</script>`

How can I handle it buddies?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Gravity Forms reprocesses the submitted value for calculation fields to ensure that the calculation is untampered. You'll need to do the same logic on the server side. Try the PHP version of this filter: gform_calculation_result

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_calculation_result/#php-version

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, Could you explain how the code works and how should I change it for my purpose?